# how to build server level custom error page in tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

i have multiple web applications deployed on one tomcat web server. for all deployed web application, i want to display same 404.jsp page if 404 error occurred in any web application.

One way is to put an entry of 404 in each web application's web.xml and give proper location to the 404.jsp.

Is there any way so that all web application will display ROOT's 404 page on 404 error??

Thanks,
Pavan

Answer (score 25):

You can add this to the $CATALINA_HOME/conf/web.xml

```
<error-page> 
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error/404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

And add a webapp that has the page and will answer to the URL under `<location>`

Comment: where would the file 404.html should be kept in your case, inside $CATALINA_HOME/error/404.html

Comment: @nishu: we actually have the error file in an apache HTTPD server as it is also used as a proxy.
Alternatively, I guess you could create an error webapp that just holds those pages and is on the correct context.

Comment: Where should we need to place the 404.html?

Comment: @Pasupathi the point is that we point to a URI so, depending on your setup, it might be in different places. You might want to change the URI to something else.
But, in this example, it is to show the 404.html from the ROOT webapp in tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open web.xml under conf/
2. goto the bottom of the page.

add these lines for each http error code.

```
<error-page>
 <error-code>404</error-code>
 <location>/error.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
 <error-page>
 <error-code>500</error-code>
 <location>/error.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
```

Refer to the screenshot.

[image]

3. create a tiny error.jsp

```html
<html>

<body>

<h1>
    <center>The Page You looking for is not available, please connect with administrator.</center>
</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

refer to the screenshot

[image]

4. Deploy it into ROOT folder of tomcat

refer to the attached screenshot.

[image]

5 results.

[image]