# Set up 404 page in tomcat for multiple webapps

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

I need to configure a custom 404 page in tomcat 6 and I want to avoid duplicating the files for each webapp (my plan B is to use symlinks but I'd like to avoid those as well).

This [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914575/how-to-build-server-level-custom-error-page-in-tomcat) suggests creating a new 'error' webapp and putting the custom page files in there. But then I haven't figured out how I set up the custom 404 configuration in web.xml to use this url `http://host:port/error/NotFound.html`

If I set it up like this:

```
<error-page>
   <error-code>404</error-code>
   <location>/error/NotFound.html</location>
</error-page>
```

It's relative to the root of the particular webapp that the user is in at that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "location" parameter is relative to a resource located in your app. Therefore it can not access an external file.

And the plan B is not the best solution because in case you redeploy your app, you should also recrate the symlink.

You may try for a plann C, using a simple jsp page (in every application) that redirects where you like. 
Eg:

**web.xml:**

```
<error-page>
   <error-code>404</error-code>
   <location>404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

**404.jsp**

```
<% response.sendRedirect("http://host:port/error/NotFound.html"); %>
```