# Spring Boot filter for non-existing endpoint

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, spring-security

I am developing a REST API using Spring Boot, currently I am facing a problem with handling requests to non-existing endpoints.

A preferred way to handle this case would be a specified HTTP status code returned with message in JSON about not supported method, at the moment Spring keeps returning blank response with HTTP 200. How could be it done with Spring? Somekind of filter?

**Edit:**

For sure, I'm not calling an existing endpoint, e.g. I can call endpoint:

```
localhost:8080/endpoint/bla/void/test
```

and it has the same result as I mentioned. The case might be mine Spring Security configuration, I've implemented a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, which has `configure` method with following attributes:

```java
httpSecurity
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .successHandler((httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, authentication) -> httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK))
        .failureHandler((httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, e) -> httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND))
        .usernameParameter("email")
        .passwordParameter("password")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
    .logout()
        .logoutUrl("/logout")
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/index")
        .logoutSuccessHandler((httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, authentication) -> httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK))
        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .permitAll();
```

About the container, I am using Tomcat and I have not defined any 404 error pages.

**Edit: (doubled from my comment)**

Now I've noticed that if the project is running within embedded Tomcat, the non-existing method handling functionality just works. However if I deploy my project to external Tomcat container it keeps returning HTTP 200. Could someone explain this behaviour to me?

Comment: As @dur stated, when u call a non existing end point Spring should return 404 not 200. I think u may be calling an existing end point. Do you have spring security or any other filters. If possible paste your Controller and the url your calling here..

Comment: @dur: No I didn't. Just regular Maven dependency configuration: 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: @Bnq: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13916212/5277820) answer, if you configured a Tomcat default error page.

Comment: @Bnq: Did you call the URL in both cases with your browser or with another tool (cURL, SoapUI, ...)?