# Why is the error not redirected to my error page in JSP

Tags: jsp, custom-error-pages

I am creating a program in which I have a HTML page(Example9.html) in which after clicking button a JSP page(Example10.jsp) is getting called which has a link to go to another JSP page(Example12.jsp). But if the second JSP page (Example12.jsp) is not founnd then it is showing 404 error but I want it to redirect to my custom created error JSP page(ErrorSheet.jsp) if there is any error but the problem is that my error page is not getting called.

How to call my error page(ErrorSheet.jsp)

Here is my code

Example9.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="Example10.jsp">
<input type="text" name="uname">
<input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Example10.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page errorPage="ErrorSheet.jsp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Example10</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
String name=request.getParameter("uname");
session.setAttribute("username",name);
 %>
<br> 
 <a href="Example12.jsp">Click Here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

ErrorSheet.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page isErrorPage="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Error Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Sorry the following exception occurred</h1>
Exception is:<%=exception %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Why is the error not redirected to my error page in JSP" - why do you expect it to???

Comment: I want to open ErrorSheet.jsp I created above when any error occur

Comment: There's a big difference between "why" and "how". Take a few minutes and try to improve your question in order to express what is it you want to achieve. Also, it would be helpful if you provide relevant information such as - what webserver are you using (tomcat?), OS, etc. Further, you should do some googling before you post such a question, you might find questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914575/how-to-build-server-level-custom-error-page-in-tomcat) which already answer your question.