# Apache Fronted with Tomcat in PCF

Tags: apache, tomcat, cloud-foundry

We have to achieve Apache-fronted Application using tomcat for java build pack in PCF :

Can we use multiple build pack for this approach ?
or
Can we use Apache  proxy_http_module to use this approach?

Is any alternative option is recommended by PCF?

Could you please guide us and your suggestion is more useful for us.
Thanks for your support.

Comment: What is the reason you must use Apache Web Server as a front end? What is driving that requirement? It's likely to be unnecessary, but we'd need to know your requirements better to recommend some other more CF appropriate solution.

Comment: Thanks for immediate response. our legacy application is using Apache HTTPD server and having more directives like Document root, rewriteEngine, rewriteCond, rewriteRule, Script Alias, Alias, Error document, Errorlog, ServerName, ServerAlias etc., We are migrating to Pivotal Cloud Foundry for this legacy application as Java Build Pack but it embedded with Tomcat server doesn't met our Apache HTTPD requirements. Hence we need Apache as Frontend and tomcat as backend to deploy our application. I hope , you understand my requirements, Could you please provide any recommendation approaches >

Answer (score 1):

Before Cloud Foundry, you would often run Apache Web Server (HTTPD) in front of Tomcat as a load balancer and possibly to serve up static content. You might also use some of its features like rewrites or authentication.

In Cloud Foundry, this is really not necessary. The platform provides you with load balancing out of the box, and Tomcat can generally do the rest.

For example:

- Tomcat can serve up static content. It happens with the default configuration and performs pretty well. If you need to squeeze more performance out of Tomcat, you can always enable the APR connector which uses the same C libraries used by HTTPD, and can give a modest performance boost for certain workloads (your mileage may vary, so test & confirm its actually helping).
- `ScriptAlias` is for configuring CGI. Most Java apps don't need that, so you can skip it. If you do indeed have CGI requirements, perhaps there are actually multiple apps here, and you can separate and push them separately on CF. If all else fails and you must do CGI in the same app, Tomcat does have support for CGI -> https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/cgi-howto.html
- `ErrorDocument`. You can fully customize HTTP response codes with Tomcat. It's done through web.xml, so you can do it at [the server level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13916212/1585136) or in your app. See the `<error-page>` tag of web.xml.
- `AuthType`. Tomcat has it's own authentication & authorization mechanisms. These cover the typical integrations like LDAP. See here -> https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/realm-howto.html

Hope that helps!